# NSMain Bundle not finding video files

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am trying to play a video in my application, but I am unable to do so as when I try to find the file using NSMainBundle it keeps returning null and I don't understand why. Here is my code

```
NSString *filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"big-buck-bunny-clip" ofType:@"m4v"];

    NSLog(@"%@", filepath);
```

What I don't understand is that it finds sound files fine, as I have a mp3 sound file in the main bundle and when I use it to find that, its fine, but with videos it finds nothing. I have an mp4 and an m4v video file in my bundle and it returns null when I try to find either of them. I tried clearing cache, deleting the app from the simulator, running it again but same thing. It is driving me insane.

Has anyone had this problem before? What am I missing?? I have downloaded the tutorial from

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/mediaplayer-framework_mpmovieplayercontroller_ios4/

and copied the code over exactly, and yet still getting null.

Any help would be much appreciated!!

EDIT:

I created a new project quickly and copied the video over, and it prints fine from there, so why is it in this one application it isn't finding any videos? Very bizarre!!

Comment: Check your build settings / project settings, especially if the video files are correctly included within your app bundle. Sometimes XCode tends to forget some file.

Comment: That was the problem!! Soo simple, put your response as answer and I will accept. Can't believe I didnt think of that before, programming while hungover is never fun. Cheers!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it is because you have not added the video to your bundle, check your project's setting. That copy resource(I forget the accurate name).